# Search the front of a string to replace the end of the string Perl

Tags: string, perl, replace, split

After getting some help here is what I have come up with (I was hoping to learn by trying to put multiple scripts together).  The script below will do the HW and OW replacements but does not run the if statement.

```
*#*!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings 'all';
$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 
while (<>) {
   s/HW/HT/g; # do the replacement of HW with HT
   s/OW/OT/g; # do a second replacement OW with OT
*#* Hopefully run the if statement       
   my @parts = /\s*\S+/g;
   if ( $parts[1] =~ s/([HO])W/$1T/ ) {
    $parts[5] = sprintf '%*d',
            length $parts[5],
            $parts[1] =~ /HT/ ? 2002 : 2001;
      }
print @parts, "\n";
}
```

I have left the rest of the post below in case people have similar problems.

I would like to use Perl to replace text in a file by searching for specific letters at the beginning of the string. For example here is a section of the file:

```
 6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000     0     5     7
 7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000     0     5     6
 8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000     0     9    10
 9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000     0     8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000     0     8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000     0    12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000     0    11    13
```

I would like to use `HT` as the search and be able to replace the "0" in the column of zeros with `2002`. I know how to replace the entire column of zeros but I don't know how to make it line specific.  After using HT as the search I need to then search `OT` and replace the `0` column with `2001`.

Basically I need to search a string that identifies the line and replace a specific string of that line while the text that lies between is variable. The output needs to be printed to a new_file.xyz. Also I will be doing this repeatedly on lots of files.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the python code that I was using but could not figure out how to make the "file.txt" be a variable to accept the file typed after the command. This code requires that I change the "file.txt" to be the name of the file every time I use it. Also I could not get it to print to a new file.

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        if "HT" in line:
            new_line = line.replace(' 0 ', '2002')
            new_lines.append(new_line)
        else:
            new_lines.append(line)
    content = ''.join(new_lines)
    print(content)
```

I have been able to do some of the work in Perl and was hoping to have a single script that would carryout all of the replace steps in sequential order since all of the `HT` start out as `HW` and all the `OT` start out as `OW`.
Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   s/HW/HT/g; # do the replacement
   s/OW/OT/g; # do a second replacement
   print; # print to the modified file
}
```

Thanks for your help.
Oh and I am unfortunately limited to Python 2.7 as someone suggested code for python 3.0.  I am purely a user of a university cluster but will ask about upgrading python.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you come up with in Python that didn't work? Please show us your code and explain what part doesn't work.

Comment: I am also hoping to use PERL because I have already figured out how to replace the HW with HT and OW with OT and I was hoping to be able to combine everything into a single PERL script to run on any input file.

Comment: If you already have that, show it please. You can [edit] your question. The way it is now, the community will close it, because it looks like you want us to do your job for you. We don't like that around here.

Comment: The main thing in PYTHON was that I could not figure out how to take peoples suggestions and get them to print to a new file, and I could not figure out how to make "file.txt" a variable to be the file that is typed adjacent to command.  Here is what I did in Python:#!/usr/bin/python

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = []

for line in lines:
    if "HT" in line:
        new_line = line.replace(' 0 ', '2002')
        new_lines.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_lines.append(line)


content = ''.join(new_lines)
print(content)

Comment: Here is what I can do in PERL that I admit is very easy but took me quite a bit of tinkering.  #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   s/HW/HT/g; # do the replacement
   s/OW/OT/g; # do a second replacement
   print; # print to the modified file
}

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add that code there. And use proper markup. It's impossible to read from the comments.

Comment: *"be able to replace the "`space0space`" with `2002`"*  You want `-0.502000     0     5` replaced with `-0.50200020025`? I doubt it. You need to be precise in your specifications.

Comment: I was trying to use the "space0space" as the search string since it will identify the column of zeros and not just all the zeros.

Comment: The languages are ***Perl*** and ***Python***. Very few modern languages have acronyms for names

Comment: Perl is hardly modern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it uses fixed-width fields, so

```
sub trim { $_[0] =~ s/^\s+//r =~ s/\s+\z//r }

while (<>) {
   my $code = trim(substr($_, 2, 4));
   if ($code eq "HW") {
      substr($_,  2, 4, "  HT");
      substr($_, 43, 6, "  2002");
   }
   elsif ($code eq "OW") {
      substr($_,  2, 4, "  OT");
      substr($_, 43, 6, "  2001");
   }

   print;
}
```

---

Cleaner:

```
sub parse {
   my ( @format, @row );
   while ($_[0] =~ /\G\s*(\S+)/g) {
      push @row, $1;
      push @format, '%'.( $+[0] - $-[0] ).'s';
   }
   return ( join('', @format)."\n", @row );
}

while (<>) {
   my ($format, @row) = parse($_);

   if    ($row[1] eq "HW") { $row[1] = "HT";  $row[5] = 2002; }
   elsif ($row[1] eq "OW") { $row[1] = "OT";  $row[5] = 2001; }

   printf($format, @row);
}
```

Comment: Hello ikegami,  First: Thanks for formatting my questions I am trying to learn how to use this better!  Thanks for the script I am going to try to understand it but may ask you some follow up questions if I get confused.

Comment: I am going to test both and see if I can figure out how to add in a section on HW replace with HT and then do find HT and replace the 0 with 2002 etc.

Comment: @Drewucla: You should have presented the entire problem at the start. This is best done in a single pass instead of two stages. See my answer.

Comment: Hello, the script above worked great, but I tried to modify it to replace all HW with HT and all OW with OT BEFORE running the Borodin if statement.  The code only did the HW and OW replacements and not the if statements, why?  I will put the code in the questions (hopefully formatted correctly)

Comment: You do `s/HW/HT/g`, then you check if a second `s/HW/HT/g` succeeds. Of course it won't. Get rid of the first `s/HW/HT/g`. /// Added a cleaner solution

Comment: I just saw ikegami's answer and that is doing all the replacements based on character spacing (is that what the 2, 4, 43 and 6 are?).  I will try to see if I can get this working. Thanks ikegami.

Comment: ug, please don't use the one with the hard-coded numbers!

Comment: I will spend the day trying to understand ikegami's script, but THANK YOU.  It works great.  Is there a way that I am supposed to "upvote" you and Borodin and others that have been helpful?

Comment: Upvoting is good. and you should accept one of the answers (by checking the mark) next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

So what you *really* want to do is to change all `HW` to `HT` and `OW` to `OT` in the second column, and change column six to 2001 if for `OW` and 2002 for `HW`?

That looks like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my @parts = /\s*\S+/g;

    if ( $parts[1] =~ s/([HO])W/$1T/ ) {

        $parts[5] = sprintf '%*d',
                length $parts[5],
                $1 eq 'H' ? 2002 : 2001;
    }

    print @parts, "\n";
}


__DATA__
 6  HW     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000     0     5     7
 7  HW     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000     0     5     6
 8  OW    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000     0     9    10
 9  HW    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000     0     8    10
10  HW    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000     0     8     9
11  OW    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000     0    12    13
12  HW    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000     0    11    13
```

#### output

```
 6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000  2002     5     7
 7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000  2002     5     6
 8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000  2001     9    10
 9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000  2002     8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000  2002     8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000  2001    12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000  2002    11    13
```

---

In case it is important, this solution takes care to keep the positions of all the values constant within each line

The lines to be modified are selected by checking whether the second field *contains* the string `HT` or `OT`. I don't know if that is adequate given the small data sample that you offer

This is for demonstration purposes. I trust you are able to modify the code to open an external file if necessary and read the data from a different file handle from `DATA`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my @parts = /\s*\S+/g;

    if ( $parts[1] =~ /[HO]T/ ) {

        $parts[5] = sprintf '%*d',
                length $parts[5],
                $parts[1] =~ /HT/ ? 2002 : 2001;
    }

    print @parts, "\n";
}


__DATA__
 6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000     0     5     7
 7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000     0     5     6
 8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000     0     9    10
 9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000     0     8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000     0     8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000     0    12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000     0    11    13
```

#### output

```
 6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000  2002     5     7
 7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000  2002     5     6
 8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000  2001     9    10
 9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000  2002     8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000  2002     8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000  2001    12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000  2002    11    13
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to trying to do this.  I have spent many years working on small molecules and just used x and dd in vi!  We are now moving into 100s of molecule systems. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use a regular expression to perform string substitution. IMO, you should do all your operations in a single substitution because it is not more complicated, it is probably faster and less error prone (because shorter).

Here is how I have understood your requirement:
In your lines, you have a H or a O followed by a T or a W that you want to force to T, then 3 fields you want to copy, then a 4th field. If the 4th field is 0,  you want to replace it by 2002 or 2001 according to the letter H or O.

This gives:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/(\s*)([HO])(T|W)(\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\d+)/$1.$2.'T'.$4.($5 == 0 ? ($2 eq 'H' ? '  2002' : '  2001') : $5)/eg;
    print $line;
}
```